# Custom directives on AngularJS pages without specific ng-app module set

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-directive

I have some simple pages that don't need a specific application module to be provided in the `ng-app` attribute. But those pages also use some of my custom directives.

As it seems natural I've put all my directives in separate *namespace* (namely module) i.e. `MyApp.Directives`.

This is all great when I also provide my application module, because I add `MyApp.Directives` as dependency and it works.

```
angular.module("MyApp", ["MyApp.Directives", ...])
```

**But**. As said I also have some very simple pages, that don't really require any particular application module because they don't need any custom controllers or anything. They're just driven by `ng-...` attributes/directives.

### Question

I know I can simply add all my custom directives to `ng` module and they will become accessible to all pages. Those with custom application module and those without. But this beats the purpose of modules, so I'm wondering if there's any other way to tell dependency injector of my additional directives/filters?

I would like to avoid any unneeded code in my application to keep is small and maintainable. (what AngularJS is all about). What I'm looking is actually some sort of hack that I'd be using in my directives' files to make `ng` module aware of my directives but without adding them to `ng` module directly... A rather advanced Angular question as it likely involves some internals manipulation.

I've tried manully adding my directives' module to `angular.module("ng").requires` array but that didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

#### #1) If you only have one module you can do it with `ngApp`:

```
<html ng-app="MyApp.Directives">
```

#### #2) If you have multiple modules you can use `angular.bootstrap` like so:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
  angular.bootstrap(document,['MyApp.Directives','MyApp.Filters']);
});
```

#### #3) Or just create a simple module for declaring dependencies:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

......

<script>
  angular.module('myApp',['MyApp.Directives','MyApp.Filters']);
</script>
```

---

#### If we could only write something like this:

```
<html ng-app="MyApp.Directives  MyApp.Filters">
```

**I made a patch to the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.12/src/Angular.js):**

```
function angularInit(element, bootstrap) {

// some code

  if (appElement) {
    bootstrap(appElement, module ? module.split(/\s+/) : []); // split by spaces :)
  }
}
```

Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/kSrY3WYzLG39NJ4UgTRM?p=preview

Comment: Maybe I haven't made myself clear enough. I want to avoid unneeded code so #2 and #3 are out, but #1 is actually out as well because I have common directives and filters I'm using on my pages (each have their own module)... What I'm looking for is actually some sort of hack that would add my directives and filters to ng's injector so it would be able to instantiate them but without adding them to `ng` module directly. This is a rather hackish/highly advanced angular js question I'm asking.

Comment: It would be great if I could provide more than one module name with `ng-app` attribute as it's possible when calling manual `.bootstrap`, but it doesn't seem to be possible.